# How to generate telegram links which will forward a file or msg from other channel to the user

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I have seen some websites where I press a button then the browser asked a permission to open telegram app. When I give the permission then the app opens on a Telegram Bot. If I press start button then bot forwards a message. How do they do it?? Any reference or link will be appreciated.